# No Suitable Driver Found. Java JDBC mysql connector

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Here is my code:

```
import java.sql.*;
import com.mysql.jdbc.Driver;

public class Main {

    public void connect() {
        Connection con = null;


        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/mydb", "dev", "pass");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            if (con != null) try { con.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main m = new Main();

        m.connect();
    }
}
```

I have imported mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar as a library in IntelliJ and as you can see the driver is imported in the code.

But I get:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/mydb
```

I have looked at countless stack overflow questions and I can't figure out what more it needs to at least attempt a connection. I have a local SQL server running, and I've double checked the port and database name.

Any ideas would be appreciated, thanks.

EDIT: this is not a duplicate. The solution to the other question that someone flagged is not relevant here. I had already added the jar as a library for the project, as described in the other question. Also, the crash doesn't happen on the "Class.forName" part, it crashes on the subsequent line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IntelliJ: mysql connector driver not found, despite being loaded as a library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22367323/intellij-mysql-connector-driver-not-found-despite-being-loaded-as-a-library)

Comment: @JohnyThomas No it isn't. That one is ultimately about a compilation error.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong flag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a colon character.

```
"jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/mydb"
```

should be

```
"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb"
```

See [Connecting to MySQL Using the JDBC DriverManager Interface](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html).

The missing colon means that the driver manager will attempt to look for a driver provider called `"mysql//localhost"` rather than `"mysql"`.  Of course, no such provider exists.

---

<sup>The Class.forName call in your code is not necessary.  But the fact that the call succeeding is a strong clue that the problem is NOT that the driver class is missing. It should cause the reader to look for **other reasons** why `DriverManager` couldn't find the driver.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

```
jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/mydb
```

You are missing a colon after `mysql`.

NB the `Class.forName()`line hasn't been necessary for ten years.

Answer (score 0):

The JDBC connection string for MySQL has been well explained [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) in the MySQL documentation. Based on that, the mistake that you've done here is a simple miss of colon after the database type, `mysql`

You're connection string (without the credentials, though) is going to change from this:

```
"jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/mydb"
```

To this:

```
"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb"
```